# How to get two functions to be minimized on the same scale?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

I want to minimize the function

$$
\underset{x}{\text{minimize}}\left[\underset{i}{\Sigma}(x_i - w_i)^2 + (x^TPx - 1)^2\right]
$$

subject to some constraints, and where $x$ is the minimization variable, a vector, $w$ is a known desired vector and $P$ is a known PSD matrix.

The issue is that the first expression $\underset{i}{\Sigma}(x_i - w_i)^2$ and the second expression $(x^TPx - 1)^2$ are on different scales, so any minimizer I use will penalize the expression with the larger scale much more heavily.

What would be the best and most straighforward approach to get the two expressions on the same scale?

Comment: The x in the second term will be x^4 while the x in the first term are x^2. Right? If so, do you really need to square the second term, or is it because you need its absolute value?